# Decorator on generator doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, generator, decorator

I'm trying to create a decorator for a generator function.
But there is some issue with the declaration.
What i'm doing wrong?

```
function  nothing (target, key, descriptor) {
  const fn = descriptor.value
  descriptor.value = function (...args) {
    fn.apply(this, args)
  }
}    

class Test {
  @nothing
  *b(x) {
    const y = yield x
    return y + 1
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Unexpected token (36:8)
  34 | class Test {
  35 |   @nothing
> 36 |   *b(x) {
     |         ^
  37 |     const y = yield "a"
  38 |     return y + 1
  39 |   }
```

Example in babel online:

[image]

Comment: Please share your babel settings. Notice that decorators are not part of ES6.

Comment: Does your decorator work on standard method definitions?

Comment: Yes in generally decorators work

Comment: "presets": [
    ["env", { "modules": false }],
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime", "transform-decorators-legacy"],

Comment: When I try in Babel online, I get the message "*repl: Decorators are not officially supported yet in 6.x pending a proposal update.*"

Comment: The babel online was only for the picture i'm working on my environment, but anyway if you want to try online you can try here:

Comment: http://henryzoo.com/babel.github.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=%0A%0Afunction%20%20nothing%20(target%2C%20key%2C%20descriptor)%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20fn%20%3D%20descriptor.value%0A%20%20descriptor.value%20%3D%20function%20(...args)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn.apply(this%2C%20args)%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aclass%20Test%20%7B%0A%20%20%40nothing%0A%20%20b(x)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20y%20%3D%20%22a%22%0A%20%20%20%20return%20y%20%2B%201%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A

Comment: Ah, yeah, that's babel 5. Which seems to have the same bug but no warning message.

Comment: This issue happens on this version of babel too: 6.24.1 (babel-core 6.24.1)